# Labels are overriding the records

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Everything working perfectly I am getting little bit issue. I have two fields Email and password. My Email id and password are saved in the browser. When I hit my side on URL then I am getting email and password both in the field automatically filled but my placeholder is overriding the fields records. I have to display label below of the text field.  Please check below image.
[image]

```js
(function() {
  // trim polyfill : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-      US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim
  if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    (function() {
      // Make sure we trim BOM and NBSP
      var rtrim = /^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g;
      String.prototype.trim = function() {
      return this.replace(rtrim, '');
    };
    })();
  }

  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input.input__field')).forEach(function(inputEl) {
  // in case the input is already filled..
    if (inputEl.value.trim() !== '') {
    classie.add(inputEl.parentNode, 'input--filled');
    }

    // events:
    inputEl.addEventListener('focus', onInputFocus);
    inputEl.addEventListener('blur', onInputBlur);
  });

  function onInputFocus(ev) {
    classie.add(ev.target.parentNode, 'input--filled');
  }

  function onInputBlur(ev) {
    if (ev.target.value.trim() === '') {
      classie.remove(ev.target.parentNode, 'input--filled');
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/js/classie.js"></script>
<link href="https://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/css/set2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="content bgcolor-4">
  <h2>Ruri</h2>
  <span class="input input--ruri">
    <input class="input__field input__field--ruri" type="email" id="input-26" />
    <label class="input__label input__label--ruri" for="input-26">
      <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--ruri">Email</span>
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="input input--ruri">
    <input class="input__field input__field--ruri" type="password" id="input-27" />
    <label class="input__label input__label--ruri" for="input-27">
       <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--ruri">Password</span>
    </label>
  </span>
</section>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you wanted to have a `placeholder` for both `email` and `password` fields?

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr. eeya, I am using this plugin for text field https://tympanus.net/Development/TextInputEffects/index2.html

Comment: I am not using any placeholder.That labels are displaying like above image

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a class `input--filled` on each of your `email` and `password` element parent `span.input--ruri` if you've placed each of their values (assuming that its not an empty string) automatically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oInputEmail = $('#input-26');
    if ($.trim(oInputEmail.val()) !== '') {
       oInputEmail.parent().addClass('input--filled');
    }

    var oInputPass = $('#input-27');
    if ($.trim(oInputPass.val()) !== '') {
       oInputPass.parent().addClass('input--filled');
    }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle to help you: 
http://jsfiddle.net/1Ld08fxf/

Hope this helps for your case

Comment: Thanks for replying, fields are auto-filled because credentials are saved in the browser and when I clicked on the field then Email label is showing below like demo.

Comment: Sorry For delay reply. where should I add class input--filled ?

Comment: I checked your code. It is working only for email, not for password.

Comment: Now I got it I added  <span class="input input--ruri input--filled "> to both email and password and working perfectly. Thanks for your help. Upvote from my side

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Kindly mark this answer 'acceptable' if you think the answer is helpful for you

Comment: I am getting one issue.. It is working on email but not working on Password.

Comment: I check in source file email span is getting input--filled but password span is not getting

Comment: Can you show me the output you've get when you do the ff: console.log(oInputPass.length, oInputPass.val(), oInputPass.parent().attr('class'));

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am not expert in scripting. Can you help me where should I add above code?

Comment: Place this code after the [if] statement's (e.g if $.trim(oInputEmail.val()) closing brace (e.g } )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147065/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-eeya).